# How to implement ajax in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to use ajax in my laravel project. but it's showing me an error while dealing with ajax request like

> POST http://localhost/hr_management/user/process-Requisition-Form 404 (Not Found)

can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid route entry for `/hr_management/user/process-Requisition-Form` in routes.php? If so, ensure that it uses post instead of get, for example:

```
Route::post('/hr_management/user/process-Requisition-Form', 'HomeController@processAjaxRequest');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a library like jQuery, for example, ensure you're specifying 'post'.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/hr_management/user/process-Requisition-Form',
  method: 'post'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Make Ajax request in laravel 5.1

first register your route in routes.php

```
Route::post('/your/ajax/url','yourController@ajaxProcessFunction');
```

And make a ajax request with your favorite javascript library and don't forget to send `X-CSRF-TOKEN` in request header and valid request type. 
Here is example for jQuery

```
$.ajax({
 method:'post',
 url:'{!!url('/') !!}/your/ajax/url',
 data:yourdata
 headers:{'X-CSRF-TOKEN':'{!! csrf_token() !!}'}
})
```